# Python Create File issues

Tags: python, filenames

I am trying to create multiple files as below.

```
cooling_file = open("Results\cooling.csv", "wt") 
accessories_file = open("Results\accessories.csv", "wt") 
admin_file = open("Results\admin.csv", "wt")        
console_file = open("Results\console.csv", "wt")       
grad_system_file = open("Results\grad_system.csv", "wt")         
image_quality_file = open("Results\image_quality.csv", "wt")                 
magnet_enclosure_file = open("Results\magnet_enclosure.csv", "wt")         
magnet_cryogens_file = open("Results\magnet_cryogens.csv", "wt")         
non_product_file = open("Results\non_product.csv", "wt")         
other_file = open("Results\other.csv", "wt")         
patient_handling_file = open("Results\patient_handling.csv", "wt")       
pdu_power_file = open("Results\pdu_power.csv", "wt")        
rf_pen_panel_file = open("Results\rf_pen_panel.csv", "wt")        
rf_coils_file = open("Results\rf_coils.csv", "wt")       
software_file = open("Results\software.csv", "wt")        
system_file = open("Results\system.csv", "wt")         
sys_cabinet_file = open("Results\sys_cabinet.csv", "wt")
```

Some of the files get created without any issues. However,some files (ex.accessories.csv,admin.csv and so on) output the following error:

```
 IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wt') or filename: 'Results\rf_pen_panel.csv'
```

Though I can change the filenames for the code to work, I am wondering if there is a conflict with a file naming convention. Could someone help explain.

Comment: Is it possible some of these files already exist in the directory?

Comment: `'\r'` is a carriage return, which your OS doesn't allow in a filename.  Fix by doubling your backslash `'Results\\rf_pen_panel.csv'` or using a raw string `r'Results\rf_pen_panel.csv'`.  (A raw string prepends an `r` before the first quote and stops backslashes from being interpreted.)

Comment: Even better.  `files = {name: open('Results\\%s.csv' % name, 'wt') for name in ('cooling', 'accessories', 'admin', 'console', 'grad_system')}`.  Then use `files['admin']` where you would have used `admin_file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\r` in a normal Python string literal is a carriage return, not the two characters you are expecting.  Your options are:

- Use a raw string literal, where backslashes have no special meaning: `r"Results\rf_pen_panel.csv"`
- Double the backslashes to escape them: `"Results\\rf_pen_panel.csv"`
- Use forward slashes: about the only part of Windows that requires backslashes is the command line. `"Results/rf_pen_panel.csv"`

Comment: Same goes for `\a` and `\n` as escaped literals. See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: Thank you. After reading the answers, feel my question was dumb. Thank you so much for the responses.

Comment: @continuous_learner:  Not dumb.  Just your normal every day error that you get better at catching as gain experience.

Answer (score 0):

The `\r` character is meaningful in Python, it's a carriage return (ASCII 13). Python tried to create the file `Results[carriage return]f_pen_panel.csv`

Two solutions to this:

- Escape your backslashes with an extra backslash: `rf_pen_panel_file = open("Results\\rf_pen_panel.csv", "wt")`
- Use forward slashes instead, Python interprets them as path separators: `rf_pen_panel_file =
  open("Results/rf_pen_panel.csv", "wt")`